# Firebase & Google authentication build failed => API_UNAVAILABLE(macCatalyst) ==> " Expected ',' "

Tags: swift, mac-catalyst

I have an issue with Google authentication using Firebase.
I have email and facebook authentication in my app and they are working fine, but when I add `pod 'GoogleSignIn'` to my Podfile and after installation, I get an error over building the app which is:

`API_UNAVAILABLE(macCatalyst) ==> " Expected ',' "`

Once I remove the `pod 'GoogleSignIn'` and clean the project everything works fine again. Is there any conflict between Facebook and Google Auth?
Here is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'WhichLike' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for WhichLike

  target 'WhichLikeTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'WhichLikeUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
end
```

but the important question here is:
Anyone does know how I can put together Facebook and Google authentication using Firebase in a swift application? please don't post the Firebase documentation link because I read all of them.

FYI, I am using Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1

Any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Try adding your pods under `# Pods for WhichLike`

Comment: Thanks, Blasanka but I still get the same error :(

Comment: https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/issues/489 I think you are facing the same issue . you need to use previous version of Google Sign in that supports Xcode 10. Check the link